# Importing Excel File into SQL Server 2022 using SSIS

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2022, sql-server-2022

I'm migrating my SSIS jobs into a new server. The new server is using Windows 2022 server as its OS, with SQL Server 2022 and has Visual Studio 2022.

One of my jobs uses the Excel Source along with an Excel Connection Manager. The Excel file is downloaded from the web and is a `.xls` file. I have no control over this as it is not a company file.

When I click on the Excel source in Visual Studio, I get the following error:

> The requested OLE DB provider Microsofot.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not registered.

To remedy this problem I have done the following:

1. Downloaded and Installed the 64 bit Microsoft OLE Db Driver for SQL Server
2. Downloaded the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (per step 1 instructions)
3. Downloaded and installed the 64bit version of the Access Database Engine Redistributable (2016)
4. Tried to run in 32 bit; however, it turns out that VS 2022 will only run in 64 bit
5. Repaired my installation of VS 2022 just in case it was corrupt.

These steps have not solved the problem as I still get that error. I'm not married to using this method of getting an Excel sheet into SQL Server; however, I do need to automate this process and it has to read a `.xls` file.

Please remember this SSIS job has been working for several years on my old server so I am ruling out incorrect flow/design. And I have updated the file location in the Excel connection dialog box.

Thoughts? Answers?

Comment: The driver name you specified is wrong. The Access Runtime name is `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB...`. This isn't a new change either. JET was replaced by ACE 16 years ago. What Excel source are you using? `I am ruling out incorrect flow/design` but that's *exactly* what happened. You didn't notice you were using a 16-year old driver only because you used a 32-bit IDE until now.

Comment: I can occasionally code, but apparently, I can't write coherent sentences :)....  I had already tried the easy fix of changing the runtimes to newer versions but had the same registering error.  Just with the ACE.OLEDB.12.0 not being registered in lieu of Jet.4.0.  Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the SSIS package data flow, edit the Excel Connection Manager and set Excel version to "*Microsoft Excel 2007 - 2010*". This will change the provider to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` which is the driver installed by the Microsoft 365 Access Runtime 64bit which you have already installed (point 3 in your post).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I tried changing the Excel version to Microsoft Excel 2007-2010 before and I still get an error.  HOWEVER, instead of saying Jet 4.0 is not registered, it says The requested OLE DB provider MIcrosofot.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered.  It appears that my machine is not installing the packages correctly(?) but I have no idea how to fix that.   On the bright side, my SQL job runs correctly in SQL Server; however, that doesn't help me designing things and I would really like a fix to this if just for debugging purposes.

Comment: I also went to the import wizard and imported an Excel file that way and saved the package to see if I could get it to work that way, but once again, the Excel doc was imported into SQL but the saved package wouldn't work.

Comment: Ok.  Paolo answer is marked correct because he said "which is the driver installed by the Microsoft 365 Access Runtime 64bit"  I hadn't installed that driver.  I had installed the Access Database Engine Redistributable 2016 version.  Not sure what the difference is, but I uninstalled the 2016 version and installed the 365 version and it works like a charm.  Thanks guys!